# Proxy Connection Error in Libgdx

Tags: http-proxy

I am using a proxy connection inside an university to connect to the internet. I recently downloaded Libgdx for on of my projects. Alas! it doesn't recognize my proxy port connection. How can I connect to Libgdx to download libraries using proxy:port settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Before executing: `java -jar gdx-setup.jar` you will have to set the JAVA_OPTS environment variable by running: `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"`. If you are running by double-clicking the jar file, you will have to configure the system environment variable.
Hope helps, regards!